# HTML5 Video / End of a Video Poster

Tags: html, video

```
<video controls="controls" poster="http://gifs.gifbin.com/1233925271_8be9acc.gif" style="width:800px;">
```

With the above; within the HTML5 `<video>` tag, I can add a poster; of an image or animated .gif just fine and plays / runs before the actual video is 'played'.

NOW, how can I add an image; specifically a .gif (animated .gif works with poster) that will run AFTER the video has played through?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**In short:** what you need is to add  `video.addEventListener('ended',function() {})` and trigger `video.load()` in your custom JavaScript.

Here is a related post that redirects after video is played, you may modify it accordingly - [Redirect html5 video after play](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10421554/1437962).

**References** to look for detailed information:

- [Everything you need to know about HTML5 video and audio](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/everything-you-need-to-know-about-html5-video-and-audio/)
- [Media events to which you can bind](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/embedded-content-0.html#mediaevents)
- [HTML5 Video Events and API](http://www.w3.org/2010/05/video/mediaevents.html)
- [MSDN - Using HTML5 video events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh924822%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Can you explain the "do it" part?

Comment: Yes I agree. This didn't really answer the question.

Comment: well.. inside the curly braces of the function on the ended event you would either with js or jQuery swap the video for an image with the same size and css styles as the video... how?  you can change the src attrib of the video to your image.. or just remove the video and add an image...

Answer (score 41):

A straightforward way of doing this:

```
<script>
var video = document.querySelector('video');       
video.addEventListener('ended', function() {
  video.load();     
});
</script>
```

Indeed when changing the src of a video tag you implicitly call a load() on it.

This method has the caveat to request the media URL again and depending on caching settings it may re-download the full-length media resource causing unnecessary network/CPU usage for the client.

A more appropriate way to solve this issue is to use an overlay image/div on top the video tag and to hide it when video starts. When the ended event fires just show the overlay image again.

Answer (score 12):

This is what I ended up doing to see a poster after the video finished playing:

```
# Show poster at the end of the video
$('video').on('ended',->
  $('video')[0].autoplay=false
  $('video')[0].load()
)
```

Comment: This is the correct answer (Arnaud goes into more detail on why this isn't great, but this code is cleaner and disables autoplay), it's just too bad the HTML5 spec didn't support this functionality natively.

Comment: above will add a flickr black image in safari.

Comment: how can I ipmemented this solution?

Comment: Without jQuery: 

var videoElement = document.getElementById('video-id');
videoElement.addEventListener('ended', function () {
  videoElement.autoplay=false
  videoElement.load()
}, false);

Answer (score 5):

try this

```
var video=$('#video_id').get(0);        
video.play();
video.addEventListener('ended',function(){
    v=video.currentSrc;
    video.src='';
    video.src=v;            
});
```

Comment: This is almost a plain javascript solution, which is what I wanted. I replaced the first line with getElementById() and added video.autoplay=false to prevent it from looping. Works like a charm.

Comment: This worked better for me, compared to just `video.load();` in Chrome 63/macOS. For some reason `load()` method was causing my poster frame to blink every several seconds after calling it … While I like the simplicity of `load()`, this solution did not make my poster frame blink. Not sure if the blinking poster frame was due to user error or some sort of bug (or feature?)

Answer (score 3):

Finally I got the solution: video will autoplay first-time and at end of video you will see the poster image:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/prototype/1.7/prototype.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 document.observe('dom:loaded', function(evt){
    $('#myVideo').each(function(elm){
        elm.play();
        var wrapper = elm.wrap('span');
        var vid = elm.clone(true);
        elm.observe('ended', function(){
          wrapper.update(vid);
       });
    });
 });
</script>

<video id="myVideo" poster="1.png" >
    <source src="1.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

Comment: thanks phil Collins its my pleasure to share idea with peoples

Answer (score 2):

This works for me.

```
var video=$('#video_id').get(0);        
video.play();
video.addEventListener('ended',function(){
    v=video.currentSrc;
    video.src='';
    video.src=v; 
    video.pause();          
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a poster at the end, and thats the only requirement, then i would say just add a ending frame in the video file as that poster and skip loading unnecessary JS. When the video ends you will see the end frame which is now the poster you added.

If you want to display the video poster at the end or in other words reload the video, then use custom event as shown above by EL Yusubov

Answer (score 1):

I see two ways to solve your issue.

First one will set your current frame to position 0 (the very first frame) after the video will end. You can set any frame you like. This solution is recommended.

```
<video controls id="myVideo" poster="test.jpg">
  <source src="test.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
<script>
let myVideo = document.getElementById("myVideo");
myVideo.onended = function() {
  myVideo.currentTime = 0;
};
</script>
```

The next one will reload the video source, so the poster will appear again. According to specification of `poster` in `video` it will be displayed only until the video starts once. After that, the only way to get the poster again - reload the video `src`, and a `poster`, just to make sure. Will work a little bit more stable with `poster` reloading.

```
<video controls id="myVideo" poster="test.jpg">
  <source src="test.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
<script>
let myVideo = document.getElementById("myVideo");
myVideo.onended = function() {
  myVideo.poster = "test.jpg"
  myVideo.src = "test.mp4"
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same objective, and found a solution by using jQuery to reset the source of the video to itself on ended. Now I get my animated gif poster before and after play.
Here is a simple javascript play function and the jQuery code.

```
function play()
    {
    movie_ID.play(); 

    $(document).ready(function(){
         $("#movie_ID").bind("ended", function() {
        $('#movie_ID').attr('src', 'movie_ID.src');
            });
         });   
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

solved by adding 1 extra frame (poster) at the end of the video itself, because website didnt support inserting of javascripts