# How can I use 'ended' event in .on() in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Im trying to use ended for a video tag in some dynamically generated content with on but it isn't working and idk why, this is my code.

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
$('.container').on('click','.videobox',function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    var video = $this.next('video')[0];
    if (video.paused) {
        $this.css({
            opacity: 0
        });
        video.play();
    } else {
        video.pause();
        $this.css({
            opacity: 0.5
        });
    }

}).on("ended",".test",function () { alert('asd');
    $(this).prev('.videobox').css({
        opacity: 0.5
    });
});
});
```

This is the html

```
<div class="videobox" style="position: absolute; z-index: 500; background-color: #000; opacity: 0.5; width: 473px; height: 474px;"><img src="/image/camera.png" style="position: relative; top: 45%; margin-left: 160px;"></div>
<video class="test" width="473" height="474">
  <source src="stuff.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Comment: Maybe the "ended" event doesn't bubble. What happens when you directly bind the handler to the element?

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML5 Video / End of a Video Poster](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14245644/html5-video-end-of-a-video-poster)

Comment: Try `.find(".test").on("ended", function() ..` in place of `.on("ended",".test",function () ..`

Comment: ...and preferably let us know the results

Comment: If you make an example on http://jsfiddle.net, that would be very useful to people helping to solve your problem.