# How to show html5 video poster end of video play?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-video

I want to show video poster after play. I am trying following code but no luck.

```
var video=$('#cms_video').get(0);
video.play();
video.addEventListener('ended',function(){
    this.posterImage.show();
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML5 Video / End of a Video Poster](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14245644/html5-video-end-of-a-video-poster)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is the solution I found:

```
var video=$('#cms_video').get(0);        
video.play();
video.addEventListener('ended',function(){
    v=video.currentSrc;
    video.src='';
    video.src=v;            
});
```

Comment: try to see my answer I think it is a bit simpler

Answer (score 15):

A more straightforward way of doing this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var video= $('#cms_video').get(0);       
video.addEventListener('ended',function(){
    video.load();     
},false);
</script>
```

Which is a shortcut to loganphp answer. Indeed when changing the src of a video tag you implicitly call a load() on it.

This method has the caveat to request the media URL again and depending on caching settings it may re-download the full-length media resource causing unnecessary network/CPU usage for the client. But still it does answer the question the way loganphp asked it.

If you want to bypass this caveat you can use and overlay image/div and bind a click/touchstart event on it to show the video tag and hide the overlay. When the ended event has fired just hide the video tag and show the overlay image.

Answer (score 0):

Simply at the end of video, show a div with the same src of the poster (with upper z-index or hide the video)
If you need to replay the video, bind a click event on the showed div (to switch visibility and replay)

Answer (score 0):

**video start autoplay and Poster showing at end of video **

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/prototype/1.7/prototype.js"></script>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.observe('dom:loaded', function(evt){
    $$('video').each(function(elm){
        elm.play();
      var wrapper = elm.wrap('span');
      var vid = elm.clone(true);
      elm.observe('ended', function(){
        wrapper.update(vid);
     });
    });
});

</script>
<video id="myvideo" poster="1.png" >
    <source src="1.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

Answer (score 0):

TRY THIS

```
var video=$('#cms_video').get(0);        
  video.play();
  video.addEventListener('ended',function(){
   v=video.currentSrc;
   video.src='';
   video.src=v;   
   $('#cms_video')[0].autoplay=false
    $('#cms_video')[0].load()
});
```

Answer (score -2):

Try to give your poster an `id` or class then you can do:

```
var video=$('#cms_video').get(0);
video.play();
video.addEventListener('ended',function(){
    $('#poster').show();
    // ^ Use . here if you apply class instead of if for your poster 
});
```

Comment: I don't want apply any class. I want to show video poster. Video poster means html video player has attribute name of poster, It shows while loading video player and before video play. Now I want to show this poster end of video play.

Comment: <video width="1024" height="576" poster="http://example.com/a.png" controls="controls" preload="auto" id="cms_video">
  <source type="video/mp4" src="http://example.com/a.mp4"></source>
No flash player has been set up. <a href="/pinkwater/branches/staging/admin/config/media/video/players">Please select a player to play Flash videos.</a></video>

Comment: Poster cannot be selected, since it's not an element, but an attribute of the video tag