# HTML after-video poster display

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video

I want my poster re-display after my video is finished. So I tried several methods according to [Tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14245644/html5-video-end-of-a-video-poster). My [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/efk8L/7/) is here. For some reasons, the play buttons and mute button doesn't work on jsfiddle, but they worked on my computer. So I just need to figure out how can I display my poster image again? Thanks!

The relevant code is attach below:

```
<video  id='ad' width="640" height="360" poster="img/model.jpg">

       <source src="video/model.mp4" type="video/mp4">
       <source src="video/model.webm" type="video/webm">

   </video>

<script type="text/javascript">

       setTimeout(function(){
           document.getElementById("ad").play();
       },3000);

       var video = "img/model.jpg";
       var ad = document.getElementById("ad");
       ad.onended = function () {
           ad.src = video;
       }


   </script>
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
var video = document.getElementById('ad');
video.addEventListener('ended',function(){
     //this will run after video end
});
```

Comment: thank! But I want to do everything natively, not use any js lib. Is there anyway to achieve that?

Comment: i know what you mean here. i have tried it before, i added the image source inside the ended function. but it's still not work.