# Poster to end video with html5

Tags: jquery, html, video

i need to add a poster to end video with html5 video player. 
Of course, i have searched here and looked it:

[HTML5 Video / End of a Video Poster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14245644/html5-video-end-of-a-video-poster)

So, i have this code:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/prototype/1.7/prototype.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 document.observe('dom:loaded', function(evt){
    $('#myVideo').each(function(elm){
        elm.play();
        var wrapper = elm.wrap('span');
        var vid = elm.clone(true);
        elm.observe('ended', function(){
          wrapper.update(vid);
       });
    });
 });
</script>

<video id="myvideo" width="100%" height="100%" oncontextmenu="return false;" controls poster="thumbnail.png">
<source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Now, when i go to play my video to end video not display poster to end video. I use latest browser version.
Where i have mistaked? How i can solve it? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Register the video to the `ended` event and then use the method `.load()` to reload video.

```html
<video id="video0" width="100%" oncontextmenu="return false;" controls poster="https://branditprintit.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/logo-degin-logo-design-design-art-free.png">
<source src="https://html5demos.com/assets/dizzy.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>

<script>
  var vid = document.getElementById('video0');

  vid.addEventListener('ended', stop);

  function stop(event) {
    this.load();
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Great glad I could help.