# HTML5 Video Embed - Display Poster At The End Of The Code

Tags: html, video

Poster at the end of the video in custom CMS

I tried some of the prior solutions posted here and was not able to get them working.

```
<!--new Clinton video -->

<video width="665" height="378" controls 
poster="http://b24e0d9c5fd8406f9a39-f11334ac06c72d0254094dd182c08814.r48.cf2.rackcdn.com/Clinton-Treatment.png" >

<source src="http://b24e0d9c5fd8406f9a39-f11334ac06c72d0254094dd182c08814.r48.cf2.rackcdn.com/clinton-video.mp4" type="video/mp4">

Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

I'd like to use my custom CMS c3summit2019.com and reload the poster when the video finishes. If possible without having to add other files to the CMS.

Comment: Here is the code 

<!--new Clinton video <video width="665" height="378" poster="http://b24e0d9c5fd8406f9a39-f11334ac06c72d0254094dd182c08814.r48.cf2.rackcdn.com/Clinton-Treatment.png" controls>
                        <source src="http://b24e0d9c5fd8406f9a39-f11334ac06c72d0254094dd182c08814.r48.cf2.rackcdn.com/clinton-video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                        Your browser does not support the video tag.
                      </video>-->

Comment: Might want to check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14245644/html5-video-end-of-a-video-poster