# HTML5 Video Embed Return to Poster at End of Play

Tags: javascript, html, video

I was using Video.JS but ultimately had to scrap it and go with plain HTML video embed tag.  Can someone help me with the JavaScript that will return the to start poster when the video stops playing.  I had it working in Video.JS but can't find the right code for standard HTML.

Here's the current code and I cleared out the JavaScript since it wasn't working anyway.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <video id="testimonials" width="448" height="336" controls preload="auto" poster="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/236154657/video-splash-image4.png"
data-setup='{"example_option":true}'>
    <source src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/236154657/WK%20Life%20Coaching%20Video%2012.13.mp4" type='video/mp4'>
    </video>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js">

  </script> 
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Katana314 lol, I deleted it because the 3 different variations I had previously were related to Video.JS and some of it was bad code to begin with. I have been searching for hours for 5 lines of code.  I don't need a lecture from you.  You are the first person I have dealt with in here that dishes attitude and ego instead of help.  Thanks.  I will wait for someone else.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way I have been able to find is to reset the source of the video on the `ended` event so that it returns to the beginning. The other way to handle it would be to have a div with the poster image in that you swap out for the video, but this is simpler...

```
<script>
var vid=document.getElementById('testimonials');
vid.addEventListener("ended", resetVideo, false);

function resetVideo() {
    // resets the video element by resetting the source
    this.src = this.src
}
</script>
```

Comment: does exactly what OP wanted (and me).

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Adds a `src` attribute to the video element, which shouldn't have one. Stopping by adding `this.currentTime = 0; this.pause();` helped out.

Comment: Both `onended="this.src = this.src"` and `this.currentTime = 0; this.pause();` provide a nasty flicker, which we would like to fix. I'm going to plug into `ontimeupdate`, detect when we are near the end, and `pause()` there, unless anyone has any better ideas

Comment: It also damaged the buffer. If you reload the video, any code that's trying to access the buffer and update the buffer display will break.

Answer (score 2):

A f'up to my above comment: The `onended` event fires only after the video player has expended its content, and gone to black. So between the end of video and the poster, we see a black flicker.

To prevent the flicker, I simply ran the video to near its end, then called `.load()` to park the player back onto the poster:

```
<video ontimeupdate="video_time_update(this)"
       poster="/ourMovie.png">
    <source src="/ourMovie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

...

```
function video_time_update(video) {
    if (video.currentTime > 3.3) {
        video.load();  /* parks the video back to its poster */
    }
}
```

Note that we know our video is 3.4 seconds long, AND we don't mind missing the last few frames. `video_time_update()` is lazy, and does not call for every tick.

And note that those of you serving videos of unknown duration might need `this.duration` instead of 3.3, there.

Comment: `video.load()` is the trick that I was looking for

Comment: and you should ONLY use this feature until your video department turns on the video trick that freezes the last frame. Technology obliges.

Answer (score 0):

Please go through the link below with realated infor:
[Redirect html5 video after play](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10421471/redirect-html5-video-after-play/10421554#10421554)

```
<script src="text/javascript">
// Do not name the function "play()"
function playVideo(){
var video = document.getElementById('video');
video.play();
video.addEventListener('ended',function(){
    window.location = 'http://www.google.com';
});
}
</script>
<video controls id="video" width="770" height="882" onclick="playVideo()">
<source src="video/Motion.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @Jatin I found this article a few hours ago but this refers to a more complicated request about looping another video before and after the main video.  I'm just looking for a simple return to a static poster.  Appreciate the response though.

Answer (score 0):

Below its working 100%

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function skip(value) {
            var video = document.getElementById("Video1");
            video.addEventListener("ended", resetVideo, false);
            video.currentTime = 0;
            video.currentTime += value;
            video.play();

    function resetVideo() {
        video.load();
    }
    }
    </script>
```