# Play video, then redirect to a new page

Tags: javascript, wordpress, html, video

I have a WordPress site with a page containing a video; I'd like this video to play automatically when the page is visited, and once the video has finished playing, I'd like a redirect to happen to a different page on my site.

I've followed the instruction from this post:
[Redirect html5 video after play](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10421471/redirect-html5-video-after-play)

But this doesn't seem to work for me and I can't figure out what I should do differently.

Here's the code currently on my page:

```
<script src="text/javascript">
function playVideo(){
    var video = document.getElementById('addiction-video');
    video.play();
    video.addEventListener('ended',function(){
    location.href = 'http://mywordpresssite.com/addiction-a-call-for-connection-acim/';
    });
}
</script>
<video id="addiction-video" autoplay="autoplay" controls="controls" width="600" height="300">
<source src="http://mywordpresssite.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/Addictions.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

Can anyone tell why it's not redirecting after the video has finished playing?

I have the above code directly in my WordPress page; I've tried placing the script below the html, and I've tried adding the script into my theme settings, but neither made it work.

Thank you!

Comment: Where do you call the `playVideo()` function?

Comment: Good question! Where should I be calling it? I'm not super familiar with JavaScript.

Comment: Well, when the page is loaded I suppose, something like this: `$( window ).load(function() { playVideo(); })`

Comment: Does your video play by itself at all?

Comment: Does the addEventListener work at all? So if you put a console.log there, does it show up in your console?

Comment: @bhelmet yes, the video autoplays but the redirect doesn't happen.

Comment: @muka.gergely in the console I see "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)" for `http://mywordpresssite.com/text/javascript` - so it looks like the script isn't working for some reason.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Firstly change `<script src="text/javascript">` to `<script type="text/javascript">` since you are not importing an external script file. Read a bit about [`<script>`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_script.asp) tag.

Secondly you don't need the `playVideo()` function. Rewrite your code accordingly:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var video = document.getElementById('addiction-video');

    video.addEventListener('ended',function(){
        location.href = 'http://mywordpresssite.com/addiction-a-call-for-connection-acim/';
    });

</script>
<video id="addiction-video" autoplay="autoplay" controls="controls" width="600" height="300">
    <source src="http://mywordpresssite.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/Addictions.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

You don't need `video.play();`, since you have `autoplay="autoplay"` attribute in `<video>` tag. Read about it [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp) and try it yourself [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_video_js_prop).

Thirdly keep your browser console open while writing a js code.

Good Luck!

Comment: So awesome! Thank you so much for this response, the explanation, links, and code! Works perfectly!