# how can i give a button two seperate functions in html

Tags: javascript, html, href, html5-audio

so im trying to create a button that takes you to the second page of my website aswell as playing a sound file. the problem im having is that it goes to the second page without playing the sound. currently, my code looks like this:

```
<body>
    <audio id="sound1" src="sound.mp3" preload="auto"></audio>

    <button type="submit" onclick="document.getElementById('sound1').play(); 
    location.href='page2.html';">enter</button>
</body>
```

does anyone know why this is happening, and if so, how can i fix it.

Comment: You need to play the sound file and attach an event when the sound file reached the end and redirect after it stopped playing.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10421471/redirect-html5-video-after-play


alternatively, you could just play the sound file and have a settimeout to switch page X seconds later depending how long the sound file is.

Comment: all sounds stop when you exit a page, so exiting a page immediately after starting a sound means you won't ever hear it

Comment: If the other page is yours too, you can initiate the sound on the other page. To let it know it should, use a URL query parameter or [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage)

Answer (score 2):

When navigating to a new page, the previous page's lifecycle ends, including media that's playing. Consider using a [Single Page Application (SPA)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application) pattern to change URLs and content while maintaining playing audio.